# Browser which can access only one website?

Tags: firefox, browser, firefox-extensions, web-filtering

I have a web based back-office application for my company.  I am hiring a new employee and want to give them access to the application, but they are not allowed to use a traditional web browser (for lots of complicated reasons).  Basically, I need to provide them a browser which can *only* access my website and nothing else.

To make things more complicated, there are other users of the same computer who need to retain the ability to browse the internet unrestricted.

Is there any kind of a solution for this?  I was thinking perhaps I could do a custom build of Firefox, or use some kind of plugin if one exists?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best solution I can see is adding a proxy server behind your local network with user authentication. On this proxy you can configure policy and filter every single web access of each proxy connected user to internet.

Comment: Is there a more "bundled up" solution so to speak?  I don't know if the employee would be able to properly configure a proxy and filtering.  I was hoping to be able to provide a single client application (like a modified FF build) which would do this internally.

Comment: If there is another option that do not includes a proxy, I can't remember now... But I could tell you that you could install the proxy server inside the client machine, add a administrator authentication and force clients to connect on localhost proxy to access internet...(however I never did such think, but I think it is possible... it desearves investigation)....